# Solution needed for proxy SSL server that doesn't allow server side variables

Tags: ssl, wordpress

I need to force SSL within a Wordpress website and I'm on a Network Solutions server with a private SSL and IP address. Plugins that force SSL are not working, I get into an infinite loop.
Network Solutions states that "Our proxy SSL doesn't allow server-side variables to detect HTTPS (secure). All server-side coding will always detect HTTP (non-secure), and for programs that attempt to redirect non-secure connections (http://) to a secure connection (https://) will result in an infinite loop and server error after 30 seconds"

Any suggestions on server side solutions - I don't want to use Javascript. Without forcing SSL, I'm OK on firefox but IE and Chrome give error messages due to the fact that all my internal links are http

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like you're going to be able to solve this one without JavaScript.  I'd be running away from Network Solutions as a hosting provider, myself.